# Extracting sequence and header from fasta file by known sequences

Tags: python, indexing, fasta

I am trying to do compare two files and extract the sequences which have the subset of others. And, I want to extract the identifiers too. However, what I can do is being able to extract the sequences including subsets. The example files are :

```
text.fa
>header1
ETTTHAASCISATTVQEQ*TLFRLLP
>header2
SKSPCSDSDY**AAA
>header3
SSGAVAAAPTTA
```

and,

```
textref.fa
>textref.fa
CISA
AAAP
AATP
```

When I run the code, I am having this output :

```
ETTTHAASCISATTVQEQ*TLFRLLP
SSGAVAAAPTTA
```

However, my expected output is with headers:

```
>header1
ETTTHAASCISATTVQEQ*TLFRLLP
>header3
SSGAVAAAPTTA
```

My code is in two parts, first I create the file with these sequences, and then I try to extract them with their headers from the original fasta file :

```
def get_nucl(filename):
    with open(filename,'r') as fd:
        nucl = []
        for line in fd:
            if line[0]!='>':
                nucl.append(line.strip())
        return nucl
def finding(filename,reffile):
        nucl = get_nucl(filename)
        with open(reffile,'r') as reffile2:
            for line in reffile2:
                for element in nucl:
                    if line.strip() in element:
                            yield(element)



    with open('sequencesmatched.txt','w') as output:
            results = finding('text.fa','textref.fa',)
            for res in results:
                print(res)
                output.write(res + '\n')
```

So, in this `sequencesmatched.txt`, I am having the sequences of `text.fa` that have the substrings of `textref.fa`. as :

```
ETTTHAASCISATTVQEQ*TLFRLLP
SSGAVAAAPTTA
```

So in the other part, to retrieve the respective headers and these sequences :

```
    def finding(filename,seqfile):
        with open(filename,'r') as fastafile:
                with open(seqfile,'r') as sequf:
                        alls=[]
                        for line in fastafile:
                                alls.append(line.strip())
                        print(alls)
                        sequfs = []
                        for line2 in sequf:
                                sequfs.append(line2.strip())
                                if str(line.strip()) == str(line2.strip()):
                                        num = alls.index(line.strip())
                                        print(alls[num-1] + line)


print(finding('text.fa','sequencesmatched.txt'))
```

However, as an output, I can only retrieve one sequence,which is the first match:

```
>header1
ETTTHAASCISATTVQEQ*TLFRLLP
```

Maybe I could do it without the second file, but I could not make the right loops to get the sequences and their respective headers. Therefore, I went to the long way..

I would be happy if you can help!

Comment: Is this an error : all[num-1], it's not your list alls, but a fonction in python. Did you just miss the spelling? The "s" is missing

Comment: @Bestasttung thank you! I did not notice. Now, I dont have an error but getting a nonwanted output. I am editing the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something much easier if your file is always the same structure:

```
def get_nucl(filename):
    with open(filename, 'r') as fd:
        headers = {}
        key = ''
        for line in fd.readlines():    
            if '>' in line:
                key = line.strip()[1:] # to remove the '>'
            else:
                headers[key] = line.strip()

    return headers
```

Here i'm assuming your file begin with ">headern" whatever, if not you have to add some test. Now you have a dictionnary like `headers['header1'] = 'ETTTHAASCISATTVQEQ*TLFRLLP'`.

So now to find the matches you just use that dict :

```
def finding(filename, reffile):
    headers = get_nucl(filename)
    with open(reffile, 'r') as f:
        matches = {}
        for line in f.readlines():
            for key, value in headers.items():
                if line.stip() in value and key not in matches:
                    matches[key] = value

    return matches
```

So as you have a dict with headers matching their values, you can just check in the dict if you have a sub string, and you already have the header value as a key.

Just saw you did `print(finding(....)` , your function already print, so just call it.

Comment: Thank you for your code, however, I am getting only 'None' as an output..

Comment: yes sorry, forgot the line.strip() in ```if line.stip() in value and key not in matches:```. Works fine now

Comment: thank you very much..however, I can still get only the first header and first sequence. it doesnt show me the second match..

Comment: i've just tested it with the examples you gave me, i have header1 and header3 in matches dict. so you might have missed something or you didn't give the good source file.

Comment: ```print(matches)``` :
```{'header1': 'ETTTHAASCISATTVQEQ*TLFRLLP', 'header3': 'SSGAVAAAPTTA'}```